# Java HttpUrlConnection not posting data

Tags: java, php, post, httpurlconnection

friends around the world,

Maybe I am asking the same question all over, but I have searched for a few hours but yet to find the answer,

I am trying to post an object to the server, it actually able to contact the server, but there is no data sent to the server, please enlighten me,

Here is my Java code

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            String location = URLEncoder.encode(params[0],"UTF-8");
            url = new URL("SERVER ADDRESS");
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty( "Accept", "*/*" );
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            jsonParam.put("ID", "25");
            jsonParam.put("description", "Real");
            jsonParam.put("enable", "true");
            out.write(jsonParam.toString());
            out.flush();
            Log.i("aware", jsonParam.toString());
            InputStream stream = con.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";

            while((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String json = buffer.toString();
            Log.i("json", json);
            // handle issues
            int statusCode = con.getResponseCode();
            Log.e("Response", "The response is: " + statusCode);
            out.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is the PHP Code

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$response = array();

if(!empty($_REQUEST)) {
    $myPost = json_encode($_REQUEST);
    echo $myPost;
    $myfile = fopen("request.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $myPost);
    fclose($myfile);
    $response['statusget'] = "good";
}

if(!empty($_GET)) {
    $myPost = json_encode($_GET);
    echo $myPost;
    $myfile = fopen("get.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $myPost);
    fclose($myfile);
    $response['statusget'] = "good";
}
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $myPost = json_encode($_POST);
    echo $myPost;
    $myfile = fopen("post.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $myPost);
    fclose($myfile);
    $response['statuspost'] = "good";
}
if(empty($jsonString) && empty($_GET) && empty($_POST)) {
    $response['status'] = "nothing";
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

The log is like this

```
08-10 23:44:41.954 29887-30497/com.mulai.smartsquare I/aware: {"ID":"25","description":"Real","enable":"true"}
08-10 23:44:41.994 29887-30497/com.mulai.smartsquare I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
08-10 23:44:42.119 29887-30497/com.mulai.smartsquare I/json: {"status":"nothing"}
08-10 23:44:42.119 29887-30497/com.mulai.smartsquare E/Response: The response is: 200
08-10 23:44:42.119 29887-29887/com.mulai.smartsquare I/Process: Done!
```

HERE is ::::::::::::UPDATE :::::::::::::

```
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.connect();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            jsonParam.put("ID", "25");
            jsonParam.put("description", "Real");
            jsonParam.put("enable", "true");
            out.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());
            Log.i("Posting...", jsonParam.toString());
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            Log.i("HTTP URL Connection", "POSTING");
            InputStream stream = con.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";

            while((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String json = buffer.toString();
            Log.i("json", json);
            int statusCode = con.getResponseCode();
            Log.e("Response", "The response is: " + statusCode);
```

Response is

```
    08-15 16:47:11.188 20709-21742/com.mulai.smartsquare I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    08-15 16:47:11.188 20709-21742/com.mulai.smartsquare I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
    08-15 16:47:11.188 20709-21742/com.mulai.smartsquare I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-17850-125518020: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
    08-15 16:47:11.188 20709-21742/com.mulai.smartsquare I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    08-15 16:47:11.488 20709-21742/com.mulai.smartsquare I/Posting...: {"ID":"25","description":"Real","enable":"true"}
    08-15 16:47:11.488 20709-21742/com.mulai.smartsquare I/HTTP URL Connection: POSTING
    08-15 16:47:11.568 20709-21742/com.mulai.smartsquare I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    08-15 16:47:11.648 20709-21742/com.mulai.smartsquare I/json: {"status":"nothing"}
    08-15 16:47:11.648 20709-21742/com.mulai.smartsquare E/Response: The response is: 200
```

Comment: Two things: 1. try closing the writer before making the request. 2. Try using binary writing instead of text writing (`DataOutputStream` instead of `OutputStreamWriter`).

Comment: Ok, thanks @NeriaNachum, I will try it and let you know...

Comment: Tried it, but it shown 'cannot resolve method write()' when I change 'OutputStreamWriter' to 'DataOutputStream'

Comment: It's `writeBytes`.

Comment: still nothing... Please check my update in question

Comment: In your update you're performing a GET request, which doesn't have a body. Did you try this with POST?

Comment: I was trying POST & GET, but both of them didnt sent to the server

Comment: What servlet are you using to run the Java code?  Also, what headers are being picked up by the PHP server vs what is transmitted by the Java servlet?

Comment: What do you mean by servlet? I am using Android Studio, Here is the header picked up by the PHP for the request `08-15 17:12:22.803 19051-22452/com.mulai.smartsquare I/json: {"data":[],"header":{"User-Agent":"Dalvik\/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0; SM-G900H Build\/LRX21T)","Host":"www.mulai.com","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Accept-Encoding":"gzip"},"status":"nothing"}`

Comment: FOUND THE SOLUTION!!!! add string to writebytes `out.writeBytes("data="+jsonParam.toString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found! just add string to writebytes `out.writeBytes("data="+jsonParam.toString());`

Thanks @NeriaNachum & @Jason